# jQuery/CSS3 UI list with action items library

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, jquery-ui

I am looking of a list component that allows me to select action item on tap. I was not able to find any jQuery UI/Bootstrap library. Anyone implemented similar component or has idea about such library?

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this is considered off-topic since it is not a programming question and requires suggestion for a library. Maybe you can get help from http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/